# how to use zoom button in a view android

Tags: android

I've always wanted to create an Android activity which uses zoombutton not the zoomcontroller in a view. But I don't know how to get started. I appreciate any help you would give me. If you could give me some piece of code to get started. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you actually want to zoom, just want to give you the idea of Zooming a text for a TextView here the code for it.

```
  ImageView increaseTextBtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.increaseTextBtn);

    final TextView txtTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_desc);

    increaseTextBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            txtTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,(txtTitle.getTextSize()+1f));
        }
    });
    ImageView decreaseTextBtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.decreaseTextBtn);
    decreaseTextBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            txtTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,(txtTitle.getTextSize()-1f));
        }
    });
```

in this code there are two buttons **(increaseTextBtn , decreaseTextBtn  )**  to adjust the zoom level of TextView

**Update**
For image view you can find an examle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203702/zoom-image-on-image-click-event)