# how to zoom an image by clicking on it in android

Tags: java, android

i have one image in my xml file in android project, i need to zoom it when i click on it.
can anybody help me out what code should i write to make my image zoom .

following is my xml code :

main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"

        android:src="@drawable/rtt" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You could use my library: [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)

Comment: Take a look at this android developer page: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html It explains how to perform animations like zooming in on a view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203702/zoom-image-on-image-click-event Google hard before you post any question here !

Comment: Try this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630373/android-image-view-pinch-zooming

Answer (score 0):

try using the setScaleX and setScaleY methods

```
imageview1.setScaleX((float)(1));
imageview1.setScaleY((float)(1));
```

to zoom in use a float that is more than 1, to zoom out use a float that is less that 1, to stop zooming in/out use 1
here is an example :

```
imageview1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View _view) {
        isZoomOn = !isZoomOn;
        if (isZoomOn) {
            imageview1.setScaleX((float)(1.5d));
            imageview1.setScaleY((float)(1.5d));
        }
        else {
            imageview1.setScaleX((float)(1));
            imageview1.setScaleY((float)(1));
        }
    }
});
```